# Why environment variable is not displayed with printenv in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have set environment variable in ~/.bash_profile as following.

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Then, I executed above .bash_profile file like this.

```
$source ~/.bash_profile
```

And checked exported environment variable like this.

```
$export -p
.....
.....
declare -x DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l/lib/:/usr/local/Cell"
.....
.....
```

But, when I executed below command to check environment variables setting, I can't anything about DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

```
$printenv
.....
.....
.....
```

Would anyone teach me why I couldn't set environment variable?

Comment: What does `env` show?

Comment: Did you run printenv in the same session right after export -p or env?

Comment: Is that a MacOS system? Possible that dynamic linker related variables are removed and therefore do not show up in external (opposed to shell builtin) commands. The question is more like, does it work anyway?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212945/unable-to-set-dyld-fallback-library-path-in-shell-on-osx-10-11-1. Short answer: yes, the variable is purged from the environment of the child process.

Comment: I see that the variable have not been available.
If that's the case, I should do what instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Try settings the environment variables in

```
/etc/profile
```

this will insure that the environment variable is set system wide, also restart your system instead of just doing

```
$source /etc/profile
```

$source will only load the environment variables for the current bash session, if you create a new shell that env variable will be lost

This works for me, hope it will work for you as well.